# The type is already defined in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on eclipse about Java I encountered such problem:

**This is the first class**

```
class Vehicle {
    int passengers;
    int fuelcap;
    int mpg;
}

public class VehicleDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
        int range;

        //assign values to fields in minivan
        minivan.passengers = 7;
        minivan.fuelcap = 16;
        minivan.mpg = 21;

        //compute the range assuming a full tank of gas
        range = minivan.fuelcap * minivan.mpg;
        System.out.println("Minivan can carry " + minivan.passengers + " with a range of " + range);
    }
}
```

**This is the second:**

```
class Vehicle {
    int passengers;
    int fuelcap;
    int mpg;

    void range() {
        System.out.println("Range is " + fuelcap * mpg);
    }
}

public class AddMeth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle sportscar = new Vehicle();

        int range1, range2;

        //assign values to fields in minivan
        minivan.passengers = 7;
        minivan.fuelcap = 16;
        minivan.mpg = 21;

        //assign values to fields in sportscar
        sportscar.passengers = 2;
        sportscar.fuelcap = 14;
        sportscar.mpg = 12;

        System.out.println("Minivan can carry " + minivan.passengers + ". ");

        minivan.range(); // display range of minivan

        System.out.println("Sportscar can carry " + sportscar.passengers + ". ");

        sportscar.range();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I am working in eclipse and deleting the first four line on second class I still have problem with void method. How eclipse is working with multiple classes with methods?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure what's the problem you're facing. Perhaps you could add the output / error in your question?

Comment: On which line of your code is the error displayed?  And do you have additional copies of any of the source files in different directories?

Comment: Suggestion: It's always best to spell out entire words like `Method` if you can, instead of abbreviating.  But it's especially best to avoid `Meth` as an abbreviation, because it  has another meaning that you really don't want to be associated with.

Comment: (1) Please don't include large segments of code in comments.  It's unreadable.  Edit your question instead.  (2) Even given that, I'm not sure what you're trying to tell us.  Do you have source files with multiple classes in one file?  That's generally not best practice anyway, but I really don't know how well Eclipse handles that, since I've never tried it.

Comment: Which names do your classes have? To notify someone if you edit your post or you're answering their comment you can add `@Username` (`@Frakcool` for example), the `@` is important

Comment: Why do you want to have two classes named `Vehicle`?  Java doesn't like that, unless they're in different _packages_.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the `Vehicle` class into its own file `Vehicle.java`.  Have only ONE version of it, not two.

Comment: Improve formatting